# How to populate a bash array with a file's lines

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, scripting

Populating an array from a file should be basic, but I can't get it to work.

```
    #!/bin/bash
    declare -a a
    i=0
    cat "file.txt" | while read line; do
        a[$i]="$line"
        i=$(($i + 1))
    done
    echo "${a[0]}"
```

This prints an empty line. For a file that contains the lines "Foo" and "Bar", here's the output from bash -x:

```
    + declare -a a
    + i=0
    + cat file.txt
    + read line
    + a[$i]=Foo
    + i=1
    + read line
    + a[$i]=Bar
    + i=2
    + read line
    + echo ''
```

I can't even get the readarray builtin working:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    declare -a b
    cat "file.txt" | readarray b
    echo "${b[0]}"

    + declare -a b
    + cat file.txt
    + readarray b
    + echo ''
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a basic `bash` pitfall: all segments of a pipeline execute in *subshells* by default, which means that whatever variables they create will go out of scope when these subshells terminate (the current shell won't see them).

Depending on what version of `bash` you're using, you have two options:

- [Bash v4.2+] Execute `shopt -s lastpipe` before you use the pipeline to ensure that the *last* pipeline segment runs in the current shell.
- Use input redirection (`<`) instead of a pipeline (or, in more complex cases, process substitution (`<(...)`) to ensure that your `while` loop doesn't run in a subshell:

```
 a=()
 while IFS= read -r line; do
   a+=( "$line" )
   # ... 
 done < "file.txt"
```

---

In the simple case of reading lines from a file, you can read *directly* into an array (`"${a[@]}"`, in this example):

- Bash 4.x:

  - `readarray -t a < "file.txt"`
- Earlier versions:

  - `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a a < "file.txt"`

Comment: That promises to be very handy. Thank you!